# Show a complete PHP Variable

Tags: php

im trying to show a complete Php Variable, my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["appendedInputButtonRoom"])) {

$CodeRoom = "<room xs=\"zwinky3\" ac=\"f\" sf=\"N\">" .$_POST["appendedInputButtonRoom"] . "</room>";

echo $CodeRoom;

}
else
{
echo "Error";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

So, for example: I enter "dsf" into the textbox, click "add" and `PHP` starts to work. It will just show the "dsf" part on the Site, but it should be supposed to show the code like:

```
<room xs="zwinky3" ac="f" sf="N">dsa</room>
```

like it does in the source code.

Any one got a idea?

Comment: Since when is `<room>` an HTML tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to html encode your output so the browser wont read the tags

```
echo htmlspecialchars($CodeRoom);
```